# C# Link an object to a pictureBox

Tags: c#, mvp

I want to create a simple game in Winform C# (pattern MVP) in order to develop my skills.

This game consists in a battle with 4 monsters (4 objects from the Monster class). Each monster is represented in a pictureBox (I put a picture of the monster inside). 
When a monster dies (its property "Life" is under or equal to 0), I want to put a red cross on the corresponding pictureBox .

My question is : "How is it possible to **link an object** (monster2 for example) **to a pictureBox** (pictureBox2 for example) ?"

I thought about a "switch" but I don't like it. 
About a property PictureBox too in the class Monster but I also don't like it (I don't like to mix View and Presenter).
Maybe an "event" on the property "Life" but I don't really know how to write it in order to select the right pictureBox (monster1 => pictureBox1, monster2 => pictureBox2, etc...).

I would like a code that can be changed really quick if, for example, I want 8 monsters (with 8 pictureBox) and not 4.

Here is a simple image of what I want. Here the hero attacks the third monster. Due to the attack, the third monster dies. So here, I want to put a red cross on the third pictureBox.

[image]

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Can't you just use a `Dictionary`?

Answer (score 0):

I'd make a custom user control (MonsterViewControl or something), and have it take a 'MonsterModel' object (or IMonster or whatever). You can then create a custom OnPaint method that will either draw the monster, or a red cross dependent on what the model looks like.